# Integrated webcam issue. Cannot find Lenovo EasyCamera for Ubuntu Server

Tags: lenovo, webcam

I have two laptops:

1. Lenovo B5400 Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS Server integrated webcam driver is missing
2. Lenovo B50-80 Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS eXubuntu integrated webcam driver is Lenovo EasyCamera

I need to fix the issue with the integrated webcam of Lenovo B5400.

Lenovo B5400
There is nothing on `/dev/video0`
    milen@serverp:~$ lsusb
    Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c019 Logitech, Inc. Optical Tilt Wheel Mouse
    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp.
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    milen@serverp:~$ 
Looks like the camera is not recognized at all. Probably, it is a hardware problem.

Lenovo B50-80
    ...
    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0c45:6514 Microdia    
    ...

Comment: [Edit] your post to include the output of `lsusb`

Comment: @vidarlo, 
The Lenovo B50-80 uses UI Xfce. The working integrated camera here is connected to "usb-0000:00:14.0-6/button".
The Lenovo B5400 uses gnome.


Initially (before knowing it could be usb), I wrote "It is not an usb camera, it is the integrated one in the laptop. And I think, I tried Fn+Esc/cam."

Comment: Most integrated cameras do use usb, including Lenovo.